# How to track login and scan REST-interface

Tags: python, selenium, authentication, https, scripting

I want to write a python script for a website that requires a login to enable some features and I want to find out, what I need to put in the header of my script  requests (e.g. authentication token and other parameters), so they are executed the same way as requests over the browser.

Does wireshark help with this if the website uses HTTPS?

Or is my only option executing a browser script with Selenium after a manual login?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone else with the same issue: you don't need to traffic your traffic from outside the browser. Just...

- use Google Chrome
- open developer tools
- click on the Network Tab
- clear the data
- and do a request in the tab where the dev-tools are
  open
- You should see the initial request at the top followed by
  subsequent ones (advertising, external image-server etc).
- You can
  rightclick the initial request, save it as a .har-file and use
  something like https://toolbox.googleapps.com/apps/har_analyzer/ to
  extract the headers of both or the request and the response.
- Now you know what parameters (key and value) you need in your header and can even use submitted values like tokens and cookies in your python script